# How do I compost lots of grass clippings?

Tags: compost, grass

I find that grass clippings tend not to compost well on their own, however we have lots of grass clippings to compost – so what do we do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add carbon.  Do you have dry fall leaves, extra non-printed cardboard or black&white newspaper to mix in?  Shredding these works best.

[A post that might help.](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/417/whats-the-best-way-to-increase-the-carbon-content-of-compost-heap-in-a-grassy-ga)

Comment: We have only just started composting so will not have leaves until the end of the year.  Does a garden shredder work with news paper?

Comment: I am not sure if yours does, but this one does: http://www.the-organic-gardener.com/garden-shredders.html

Comment: @Ian - Is it a rugged motorized shredder? As long as you aren't sending a folded-up copy of the Sunday edition through it, it will probably work. The ideal pile construction will have layers of greens (grass clippings), browns (leaves, newspaper, etc), and soil or finished compost. This keeps your greens from getting smelly.